# amazon ec2, is mount information stored in ami or snapshot?

Tags: amazon-ec2, mount, amazon-ami

I have ec2 instance set up where mysql DB is mounted on separate volume.
(as detailed in http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1663 )

I want to duplicate this instance set up where my application servers on duplicated instances share the DB volume which is attached to the already running ec2 instance.(I can specify mysql ip through configuration file)

Since almost every set up except the mysql ip is identical, i'd like to create an ami from the first instance and slightly modify to create 2nd,3rd instances.

The question is, the mount information stored in the first instance will take effect when I launch the 2nd instance.

I can elaborate the question,
1. I read that a volume can not be attached to more than one ec2 instance at the same time.
2. the running instance attaches/mount an volume to itself on start up.(so it seems)
3. if I were to create an ami from first instance and use that to initiate other instances, how would auto attach/mount information(which I assume, will be stored in the ami) will affect the other instances.

Answer (score 1):

Eugene,

Mounting the same device to several servers is not possible, so you better forget about this option.

The best solution is to:

1. Create a copy of your master instance.
2. Detach the created mount volume. We are going to create an image from this new instance, and you don't want the useless drive copy to be re-created every time.
3. Change the settings that you need to change, in order to make this server rely on the remote (master) mysql server.
4. Once you are satisfied with the outcome, create an image from this instance.

Good luck!
Dotan